# BS4 wont pull all the HTML?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a program to look and see what stocks are being bought. However I cannot get beautiful soup to get the information that I need.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://finviz.com/insidertrading.ashx?tc=1'
page = requests.get(url)

def main():
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
        print(soup.prettify())
        print(soup)
        
main()
```

I just need the stock ticker(4 letters on the very left on the table in https://finviz.com/insidertrading.ashx?tc=1.

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Use selenium. Data is loaded dynamically

Answer (score 0):

you just have to set headers to your request

```
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 10.0; Trident/4.0)'}
url = 'https://finviz.com/insidertrading.ashx?tc=1'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```